# If $A$ is a Dedekind domain and $I \subset A$ a non-zero ideal, then every ideal of $A/I$ is principal.

Tags: commutative-algebra, dedekind-domain

In this question I will use the following definition of a Dedekind domain:

An integral domain $A$ is a Dedekind Domain if:

1) $A$ is a Noetherian Ring.

2) $A$ is integrally closed.

3) Every non-zero prime ideal of $A$ is maximal.

I also know that every non-zero ideal $I \subset A$ can be expressed uniquely as a product of powers of prime ideals (a proof that does not use results from localization or primary decomposition can be found in Pierre Samuel's *Algebraic Theory of Numbers*).

With this information, and without having been taught localization (this is for an undergrad class in ANT) is it possible to prove the following statement:

> If $A$ is a Dedekind Domain and $I \subset A$ a non-zero ideal, then every ideal of $A/I$ is principal.

--I should point out that I can come up with a proof when I know that in a Dedekind domain $A$ if $p \subset A$ is a non-zero prime (hence maximal) ideal, then the localization $A_p$ is a P.I.D. But, as we have not been taught localization in class I cannot use it to solve the question. I also looked at Atiyah- Macdonald, and they basically prove this as Theorem 9.3, but they use results from localization and primary decomposition.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes. Factor $I = \displaystyle\prod_{i =1}^n \mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}.$ Then by the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings) $A/I \cong \displaystyle\bigoplus_{i =1}^n A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}.$ So it is enough to show each factor $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}$ is principal. The ideals of $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}$ are exactly the images of the ideals of $A$ containing $\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i},$ i.e., $\mathfrak{p}_i^{n}$ for $1\le n \leq e_i,$ under the projection map $\pi:A \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}.$ If $\pi(\mathfrak{p}_i) = \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i^2)$ then $\pi( \mathfrak{p}_i) = 0$ and $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ is a field. Otherwise, let $\alpha \in\pi( \mathfrak{p}_i) \setminus \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i^2).$ Then $(\alpha)$ is a proper ideal such that $(\alpha) \not\subset \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i^n) $ for any $n\ge 2.$ It follows $(\alpha) = \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i).$ We conclude $\pi(\mathfrak{p}_i^n) = (\alpha^n)$ and hence $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ is principal.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking if $1 < e_1$, then $A/{p_i}^{e_i}$ is not a PID (because it is not a domain), as ${p_i}^{e_i}$ is not prime in $A$. But, I get what you mean. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Rankeya How do we know that the only ideals containing $p_{i}^{e_{i}}$ are powers of $p_{i}$?

Comment: @Jackson: Let $Q$ be a prime ideal of Dedekind domain which contains $P_i^{e_i}$. So, $P_i^{e_i}\subset Q$ implies (taking radicals) $P_i\subseteq Q$; since prime ideals are maximal, $P_i=Q$. [Without going into radicals, we can argue: $P_i^{e_i}\subset Q$ means $Q$ divides $P_i^{e_i}=O_iP_i\cdots P_i$; from uniqueness of factorization into primes ideals, we get $Q=P_i$.

Answer (score 6):

**HINT** $\:$ By the approximation theorem, Dedekind domain ideals $\rm\:J\!\ne\! 0\:$ are strongly two generated, i.e. for each $\rm\:0\ne i\in J\:$ there exists $\rm\:j\in J\:$ such that $\rm\:J = (i,j)\:.\:$ Therefore every ideal $\rm\: J\supset I\:$ can be presented in the form $\rm\:J = (i,j)\:$ for $\rm\:0\ne i\in I,\ j\in J\:.\:$ Hence $\rm\ J = (j)\pmod I\ $ is principal.

**NOTE** $\ $ This property characterizes Dedekind domains, i.e. a domain $\rm\:D\:$ is Dedekind iff every nonzero ideal of $\rm\:D\:$ is strongly two generated.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But, I prove that every ideal of a Dedekind domain can be generated by at most two elements using the statement that I asked as the question here. But, you are right.