# If $A$ is a Dedekind domain, and $\{0\} \ne I \vartriangleleft A$ is an ideal, then $A/I$ is a principal ideal ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-explanation, algebraic-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

> If $A$ is a Dedekind domain, and $\{0\} \ne I \vartriangleleft A$ is an ideal, then $A/I$ is a principal ideal ring.

I have questions about a proof of the said result [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72536/if-a-is-a-dedekind-domain-and-i-subset-a-a-non-zero-ideal-then-every-ideal). I am reproducing the proof from the source (by @jspecter) below:

> Factor $I = \displaystyle\prod_{i =1}^n \mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}.$ Then by the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Statement_for_general_rings) $A/I \cong \displaystyle\bigoplus_{i =1}^n A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}.$ So it is enough to show each factor $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}$ is principal. The ideals of $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}$ are exactly the images of the ideals of $A$ containing $\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i},$ i.e., $\mathfrak{p}_i^{n}$ for $1\le n \leq e_i,$ under the projection map $\pi:A \rightarrow A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}.$ If $\pi(\mathfrak{p}_i) = \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i^2)$ then $\pi( \mathfrak{p}_i) = 0$ and $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ is a field. Otherwise, let $\alpha \in\pi( \mathfrak{p}_i) \setminus \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i^2).$ Then $(\alpha)$ is a proper ideal such that $(\alpha) \not\subset \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i^n) $ for any $n\ge 2.$ It follows $(\alpha) = \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i).$ We conclude $\pi(\mathfrak{p}_i^n) = (\alpha^n)$ and hence $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ is principal.

1. If $\pi(\mathfrak{p}_i) = \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i^2)$, why is $\pi(\mathfrak p_i) = \{0\}$?  If this holds, I understand why $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ is a field.
2. Why is $(\alpha)$ a proper ideal? If $(\alpha)$ is not proper, then $\alpha \in \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i) \setminus \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i^2)$ is a unit in $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$, i.e., there exists $\beta \in A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ such that $\alpha\beta = 1_A + \mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$. I don't see an immediate contradiction. We also have $(\alpha)\subset \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i)$, since $\pi(\mathfrak{p}_i)$ is an ideal.
3. I understand $(\alpha) = \pi(\mathfrak{p}_i)$ (assuming previous steps.) How do we get $\pi(\mathfrak{p}_i^n) = (\alpha^n)$?
4. Why is it enough to show that each "factor" $A/\mathfrak p_i^{e_i}$ is a principal ideal ring? Suppose $I$ is a non-zero ideal in $A$ with the factorization $I = \prod_{i=1}^n\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ as above, and that every $A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$ is a principal ideal ring. Let $\{0\} \ne J \vartriangleleft A/I$ be an ideal, and $\phi$ denote the ring isomorphism $A/I \to \displaystyle\bigoplus_{i =1}^n A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}$. Then, $\phi(J)$ is an ideal in $\displaystyle\bigoplus_{i =1}^n A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}$. By [this lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1166731/425395), $J = J_1 \times \ldots \times J_n$ where $J_i \vartriangleleft A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e_i}$. As every $J_i = (j_i)$ is principal, we have $J = (j_1,\ldots,j_n)$. Is this correct?

Thanks a ton!

---

P.S. The notation $A/I \cong \displaystyle\bigoplus_{i =1}^n A/\mathfrak{p}_i^{e^i}$ is terribly confusing. Isn't this a direct *product* instead of a direct *sum*? I do not wish to complicate things unnecessarily, but the direct sum doesn't function as the coproduct in the category of rings.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Comment: Did you consider asking this directly on the post? It's normal to ask clarifying questions on someone else's post.

Answer (score 1):

About your PS: there is no difference between a direct product and direct sum of *finitely many* groups or rings or modules in terms of its algebraic structure. I disagree that the use of the direct sum is terribly confusing or an unnecessary complication.

The proof at your source by Bill Dubuque is simpler than the proof by jspecter. It is based on the fact that every nonzero ideal $I$ in $A$ has two generators, where one of them can be an *arbitrary* nonzero element of $I$. That fact is proved with the Chinese remainder theorem (as is the argument you ask about) and does not require knowing that $A/I$ is a principal ideal ring, so this won't be a circular argument.

Here is a proof of the result you ask about by using the same argument that Dubuque wrote in your source. Each ideal in $A/I$ has the form $J/I$ for an ideal $J$ of $A$ that contains $I$. Pick a nonzero $\alpha \in I$, so $\alpha \in J$ and thus $J = (\alpha,\beta)$ for some $\beta \in J$. Then in $A/I$, its ideal $J/I$ is generated by $\overline{\alpha}$ and $\overline{\beta}$. Since $\alpha \in I$, we have $\overline{\alpha} = \overline{0}$ in $J/I$, so $J/I = (\overline{\beta})$ in $A/I$. Hence each ideal in $A/I$ is principal.

As for the proof you are asking about, in the ring $R = A/\mathfrak p^e$ each proper ideal has the form $\mathfrak p^i/\mathfrak p^e$ where $1 \leq i \leq e$, and this ideal a power (more precisely, the $i$th power) of the ideal $P = \mathfrak p/\mathfrak p^e$, so it suffices to show $P$ is principal in $R$ (a product of principal ideals is principal: $(x)(y) = (xy)$).

Pick $\alpha \in \mathfrak p - \mathfrak p^2$, so $(\alpha)$ is divisible by $\mathfrak p$ exactly once: $(\alpha) = \mathfrak p\mathfrak a$ where $\mathfrak p \nmid \mathfrak a$. We'll show that in $R$, $\overline{\alpha}$ generates $\mathfrak p/\mathfrak p^e$.
Since $\mathfrak p$ divides $(\alpha)$ just once,  $\gcd((\alpha),\mathfrak p^e) = \mathfrak p$, so $(\alpha)+ \mathfrak p^e = \mathfrak p$ in $A$. Reducing that equation modulo $\mathfrak p^e$, we get $(\overline{\alpha}) = \mathfrak p/\mathfrak p^e$ in $R = A/\mathfrak p^e$.

Comment: I understand the other proof - could you please help me with the actual questions in my post? Thank you!

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic I updated the end of my answer with a proof along the lines you asked about.  You should convince yourself that in a product of two rings $R \times S$, if $I = (x)$ is a principal ideal in $R$ and $J = (y)$ is a principal ideal in $S$, then in $R \times S$ the ideal$I \times J$ is principal with generator $(x,y)$:  $I \times J = ((x,y))$.  Make good use of the elements $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ to focus attention on $R$ and $S$ inside $R \times S$ (note $R \times \{0\}$ and $\{0\} \times S$ are ideals in $R \times S$, not subrings).

Comment: What if $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak p^2$?

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic well, if you already know that every nonzero ideal in a Dedekind domain admits a *unique* factorization into a product of prime ideals, then it is immediate that this can't happen. In fact, a Nakayama's lemma argument shows that for a finitely generated ideal $I$ of a commutative ring $R$, we have $I^{2} = I$ iff $I$ is principal and generated by an idempotent of $R$ - see this very nice answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/348834/73817. Since every Dedekind domain is Noetherian, the only ideals of a Dedekind domain $R$ satisfying $I = I^{2}$ are $0$ and $R$.

Comment: @esoteric-elliptic the condition is *not* that $\mathfrak p = \mathfrak p^2$ in $A$, but rather in $A/\mathfrak p^e$, which is why it is written as $\pi(\mathfrak p) = \pi(\mathfrak p^2)$.  If $e \geq 2$, then $\mathfrak p \supset \mathfrak p^2 \supset \mathfrak p^e$ in $A$, where the first containment is strict, so reducing modulo $\mathfrak p^e$ shows $\pi(\mathfrak p) \not= \pi(\mathfrak p^2)$.  So if $\pi(\mathfrak p) = \pi(\mathfrak p^2)$, then $e = 1$.